# PHP. Заблокировать форму и radiobutton на определенное время

Tags: php

Есть обычный радиобаттон. Как заблокировать его на 10 дней, после отправки?

```
<form>Радиобаттон: <input name=dig type=radio><br></form>
```

Т.е. выбрал радиобаттон, нажал отправить и он стал неактивным на 10 дней. Всего 10 радиокнопок. Если есть варианты с полями, то прошу тоже подсказать.

Comment: Используйте куки, добавляйте каждому пользователю ее, а потом проверяйте на наличие, и блокируйте, в случае необходимости. НО куки можно почистить, и тогда снова можно будет использовать данную форму. Либо делайте обязательной регистрацию, тогда точно сможете избежать проблем с очисткой кук.

Comment: В случае использования регистрации, что мне нужно сделать?

Comment: Если у Вас используется регистрация, и нужно ограничить доступ к кнопкам для зарегистрированных пользователей - просто пишите в БД когда последний раз использовался элемент, и проверяйте эти значения для каждого пользователя, подсчитывая дни